# How to delete specific hidden sub folders recursively with batch

Tags: batch-file, directory, hidden, subdirectory

A bad program left several ".data" hidden folders in every sub directory.

I have tried this so far, and it doesn't work...

```
RD /ah /s /q "D:\This Folder\.data"
```

I have many folders and sub-folders, each one has a ".data" hidden folder there that I would like to remove. If it helps, I would like to delete all the hidden folders because they are all ".data".

Answer (score 4):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims= eol=" %%a in ('
        dir /adh /s /b 2^>nul 
    ') do if /i "%%~nxa"==".data" echo rd /s /q "%%~fa"
```

This executes a `dir` command to retrieve a recursive (`/s`) list of hidden directories (`/ahd`) in bare format (`/b`). This list is processed by a `for /f` command that will check for each match if it is a `.data` folder. If it matches the condition, the folder and its contents are removed.

**note** the `rd` commands are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: Why do we need `setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion`?

Comment: @MichaelS, with extensions disabled the `for /f` is not recognized. While the usual configuration is to have them enabled by default I have found cases where it has been changed. With delayed expansion enabled (yes, the usual configuration is disabled, but not always) the code could have problems with paths that contain exclamations. And both parameters are controled by `setlocal` command. So, just to prevent problems, I have the habit to include the declaration of the precise configuration needed to run the code.

Comment: @MCND, I suggest to use also the `eol=|` option to avoid trouble with paths beginning with `;` (just in general)...

Comment: @aschipfl, I have code that uses `::` as a drive reference. While in real world I have never seen a `dir /s /b` command return a `;:` drive, I have to admit that it can be done, so, OK, I will change it. But the pipe character has the same problem

Comment: @MCND, I know, I just meant in general ;-) in your edit you defined `"` as delimiter (`eol` always uses the char. after the `=` and doesn't care about anything else...), but that's a forbidden char. for paths anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl, while getting a `;:` drive is simple, to use a quote as a drive letter in a `dir` command is not that easy (I have to test if it is possible), so I think the quote is a good election for this case.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b /o:n /adh') do (
    if "%%~nxF"==".data" rd /s /q "%%F"
)
```

`dir /s /b /o:n /adh` gives you all folders and subfolders skipping files. `for /f` iterates over all these folders. `%%~nxF` extracts the last folder name from the whole path so we can check whether it is `.data`. If this is the case `rd /s /q %%F` deletes the folder.

Comment: You need the `"delims="` or the `"tokens=*"` clauses to prevent problems with paths that contain spaces as by default the `for /f` replaceable parameter will only retrieve the fist space/tab delimited token. In the same way you use quotes in the `if` command, the folder reference in the `rd` command also needs quotes to prevent problems with spaces or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Read what you get when you type for /? then:

Use the /d

```
FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
    names instead of file names.
```

and the /r switches together

```
FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
will just enumerate the directory tree.
```

To scan folders recursivly

```
for /d /r . %%a in (data*) do rd /s /q "%%a"
```